# Fetch in React Native Expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using `fetch` in my `React Native` app using `Expo`. The problem I'm having is that there seems to be an execution of code which throws an error before the promise is resolved. Here's my code:

```
renderWithData() {
    return fetch('https://myapi.com')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((myListData) => {
      return (
        <FlatList data={myListData} renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.dataItem}</Text>} />
      );
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

The error I'm getting reads:

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
>   object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a
>   collection of children, use an array instead.

That's because I seem to be getting some type of object that I think represents the promise. This throws the error. Only a split second later, I get the array from the API call.

The code that invokes `renderWithData()` is as follows:

```
<View style={styles.listContainer}>
   {this.renderWithData()}
</View>
```

How do I get it to wait till the data are received. I thought using `then` would do it but clearly it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fetch api returns a **promise** as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Therefore you're returning a `promise` in your function `this.renderWithData()` and not a `React Element`

You must `setState` the data you get from the `fetch api` and render it dynamically in the `FlatList` as

```
state = {
 myListData: []
}

renderWithData = () => { . //... Ignore if already bound
    return fetch('https://myapi.com')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((myListData) => {
      this.setState({myListData}}
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

<View style={styles.listContainer}>
   <FlatList data={this.state.myListData} renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.dataItem}</Text>} />
</View>
```

*Assuming that `getPhoneExtensions()` is mentioned as `renderWithData()` in the last snippet*